# How to change URL query string with PHP/.htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, query-string

I want to change URL like below:

```
http://localhost/register/profile.php?user_id=23
```

to:

```
http://localhost/register/username
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a user of id 23 and username "*foo*". The easiest is to rewrite **/register/23/foo to /register/profile.php?user_id=23** as such:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^/register/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/$ /register/profile.php?user_id=$1 [L,R]
```

But if you can change profile.php to rely on `$_GET['username']` rather than `$_GET['user_id']`, you can rewrite **/register/foo to /register/profile.php?username=foo**. Use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^/register/([^/]+)/$ /register/profile.php?username=$1 [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable mod_rewrite.
The internet is full of example an tutorials for that.

One example:
http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/